# How to have a certain number of variables acordding to a main variable

Tags: c, file, variables

I'm developing a program that asks you how many disciplines you have. Next it ask the name and the grade of each;

First asks how many disciplines, and after:

```
    printf("\nInsira o nº de disciplinas: ");      
    scanf("%i", &NDISCIPLINAS);

for(i=0;i<=NDISCIPLINAS;i++)
    {
        puts("Name of discipline: ");
        scanf("%s", disciplina);
        
        printf("Grade: \n");
        scanf("%d", &notas);
    }
```

But It's not that what I really want.
**I want the program to save each discipline and grade into a different variable.**
Cause then I will want to fprintf the info to a specific file and it would be more easier if  the info is well gathered.
My real question is basically:
IF i have 5 disciplines,how can I display the name and the grade of each,line by line, into a file?

thanks guys really strugglin' here

Comment: You need an array of structures, or two arrays of strings if you've not yet learned about structures.

Comment: or why not fprintf directly to the file as you read?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways, you can achieve your goal. I'll suggest you the three of them, which are popping in my mind right now:

1. Use 2 character arrays, scan values and then store them into the file. Then reuse them (using sentinel loop).
2. Use a dynamic structure array, which contains two members in it`(Name, Grade)`, and use any function `store(name, grade)` to store values.
3. Get the no. of disciplines from the user in any `int variable`, then using a loop, get value from the user and store it directly to the file, within the loop.